# C#: Using a generic to create a pointer array

Tags: c#, generics, pointers

Afternoon all,

a little help if you please. In order to circumvent the 2Gb object limit in .NET I have made a class that allocates memory on the heap and this allows me to create arrays up to the limit of my free RAM. However, for ease of development (as it was a proof of concept) it was hard coded for longs. Now that it works I've been trying to alter the code to use generics so I can use the same code for multiple types.

In allocating the memory and correctly index the array I need an array of pointers of the same type that the array will hold i.e. a long array needs `long*[] myLargeArray`. The problem is when I use generics this declaration becomes `T*[] myLargeArray`, which always produces the error ***'Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('T')'***

Thanks in advance.

PS Before anyone asks, yes I really do need such large arrays.

Code example for a 2D array:

```
    LargeArray <int> myArray = new LargeArray<int>(x, y);

    public unsafe class LargeArray where T : struct
    {
        ...
        private T*[] tArr;
        ...
        public LargeArray(long sizeI, long sizeJ)
        {
            ...
            myLargeArray = new T*[sizeI];
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

According to the [C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx):

> Any of the following types may be a
>   pointer type:
>
> - sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float,
>     double, decimal, or bool
> - Any enum type.
> - Any pointer type.
> - Any user-defined struct type that contains fields of unmanaged types
>     only.

When you place the `struct` constraint on your generic type, the compiler does not have enough information to infer that all of the above requirements will be met (specifically the last point).

Since we don't have templates in C#, you may want to consider creating overloads of your array/pointer adapter for the numeric types that make sense, or a factory class that creates a `LargeArray` given a size of a certain type.

Comment: I think factory pattern is definitely the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

> Even when used with the unsafe
>   keyword, taking the address of a
>   managed object, getting the size of a
>   managed object, or declaring a pointer
>   to a managed type is not allowed. For
>   more information, see [Unsafe Code and
>   Pointers (C# Programming Guide).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Also I don't know if you are, but make sure you're using [fixed keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28VS.80%29.aspx) in your code.