# How can I make a pointer generic in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a `WriteableBitmap` which I use an unsafe method to plot pixels. The essential part looks like this:

```
private unsafe void DrawBitmap(WriteableBitmap bitmap, byte[] pixels)
{
         // Boilerplate omitted... 

        fixed (byte* pPixels = pixels)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                var row = pPixels + (y * width);
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    *(row + x) = color[y + height * x];
                }
            }
        }

        bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), pixels, width*pf.BitsPerPixel/8, 0);
}
```

However, it is not certain that what the user wants to plot is of the type `byte`, and it would make sense to make this method generic (i.e. `DrawBitmap<T>`) but how can I make the pointer `pPixels` of type `T*`?

Is there some other trick that will make my `DrawBitmap` generic?

Comment: "Generic" means that the same method (same IL) works for *all* types, not just the ones you're actually using as type parameter. Different integer types (byte, int, ...) require different IL, so you can't make the method generic.

Comment: I don't quite see where `pPixels` or `pixels` is coming from? Post all of the code?

Comment: But as @dtb says, you need a type which in simple terms derives from `object`, value types can not be used in generic methods. I would consider using different overloads of the method instead.

Comment: @LukeHennerley It's `color`. I've corrected it.

Comment: @LukeHennerley: That's complete non-sense. (1) value types derive from object and (2) you can use them in a generic class.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Sorry, it's early in the morning :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Using a generic to create a pointer array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631754/c-using-a-generic-to-create-a-pointer-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229029%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
public void MethodA(byte[] pPixels) {}
public void MethodA(int[] pPixels {}
//etc...
```